# PSQL Select only unique records

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Postgres db with data for analyzing the bitcoin blockchain. I have one table for all input addresses. There could be duplicate addresses and I only want to have those addresses which appears once. So my data set looks like that:

```
address
1
2
2
3
```

The result should give me only 1 and 3, so distinct will not work. I used `GROUP BY address HAVING COUNT(address) = 1` but as my dataset is really large, that takes a lot of time. Is there maybe a better way to get only unique values?

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Answer (score 0):

Your query might be faster with an index on `address`, but without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output that is just a guess.

Comment: I have an index on address, but my question was more like if there is another way to get unique records and avoid this "group by having count 1"- syntax

Comment: I don't think there is a faster way. Sorting many values takes a lot of time. An index can sometimes avoid a sort.